# Why Array of string transform in string array in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to do one service with backbone in wordpress, this have to fetch one url, and get from the url this values:

```
["C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads",
"C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014",
"C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07",
"C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/08",
"C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/10",
"C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11",
"C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/woocommerce_uploads"]
```

i stock this information in one collection, but the problem is that backbone take each one of this put in models (good in this part) but if i ask for each model the value, i getting something like

```
0:"c"
1:":"
2:"/"
.
.
```

I dont know why is this happen and how to fixed, any of you know the why of this problem? and the solution?

This is my collection

```
var CCUFFolder= Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url:ajaxurl
});
```

And the fetch

```
cCUFFolder.fetch({type:'POST',data:{action: "cuf_get_dirs"}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone's Model type is essentially a wrapper around object literals. As you are constructing *your* models from strings, Backbone is creating each model's `attributes` hash by parsing each string for key/value pairs - which is producing an array of characters. What you want to do is to construct your model's from object literals:

```
var collection_source = [
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads" },
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014" },
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/07" },
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/08" },
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/10" },
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11" },
    { "Path": "C:\\wamp\\www\\wordpress\/wp-content\/uploads\/woocommerce_uploads" }    
];

var folder = new CCUFFolder(collection_source);

console.log(folder.first().get('Path'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `parse` method in your collection:

```
var CCUFFolder= Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: ajaxurl,

    parse: function (response) {
        return _.map(response, function (item) {
            return { path: item }
        });
    }
});
```

After that you can retrieve models correctly:

```
cCUFFolder.each(function (model) {
   console.log(model.get('path');
});
```